# the command `brew install watchman` runs `chmod` but fails to install eventually

Tags: reactjs, facebook, react-native, homebrew, watchman

```
brew install --HEAD watchman
==> Cloning https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
Updating /Library/Caches/Homebrew/watchman--git
==> Checking out branch master
==> ./autogen.sh
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/watchman/HEAD --with-pcre
==> make
==> make install
install: chmod 777 /: Operation not permitted
touch //.not-empty
touch: //.not-empty: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install-exec-local] Error 1
make: *** [install-am] Error 2
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.5.0'

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
```

It is trying to `chmod 777 /` which is not good. Why is it trying to do that? Feels like that shouldn't be allowed. I tried to uninstall watchman and reinstall with this command to get a react-native to start working.

Followed steps here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/239

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok fixed it

You can install watchman without the --HEAD option (the currently tracked version of watchman is old enough to not have the issue specified). So just do a brew install watchman.

If you then get issues with your react project make sure that your project directory is a git repo (run git init if not) see:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2032

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2042

Answer (score 18):

```
brew uninstall watchman
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
brew link pcre
brew install watchman
```

Comment: In High sierra or higher the sudo ```sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local``` will fail.
One might want to use `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` instead

Answer (score 3):

Sorry about this, should be fixed now in https://github.com/facebook/watchman/commit/b35c6ed36a5f60ab3f214ddc646a8a03e03a0fee

Answer (score 1):

Fix for installing on OSX `high sierra 10.13.2` required reinstalling homebrew since it needs to work around the non-writeable `/usr/local/` folder

I had to reinstall homebrew:

uninstall:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`

reinstall:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
brew update
brew doctor
brew install watchman
```

If you are still having problems, try going to your_project/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/FileWatcher/index.js and increase the MAX_WAIT_TIME

Answer (score 0):

For me worked the same as above:

```
brew update
brew doctor
brew install watchman
```

Also make sure you have this in the jest config:

```
watchPathIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules']
```

Answer (score 0):

People on new M1, M2 macbooks use `arch -x86_64 brew install <package>`

Answer (score 0):

For me, running the following command worked:

`brew install --HEAD watchman`

For more information do consult the official documentation
[Watchman documentation from Facebook](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html)

[image: Screenshot from Watchman documentation]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33578889)