# Installing watchman for Reach Native in Mac OS X Catalina

Tags: macos, react-native, homebrew, watchman

I'm having trouble getting the latest version of Watchman to install property on Mac OS X Catalina.

I am using `Homebrew 2.2.1`. I get this error when doing a clean install of `brew install watchman`.

```
==> Pouring watchman-4.9.0_3.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall watchman`
```

Running `brew postinstall watchman` just gives me the same message. If I just try to run `watchman` I get this error.

```
while computing sockname: failed to create /usr/local/var/run/watchman/USERNAME-state: No such file or directory
```

How do I install the latest version of watchman on Mac OS X Catalina?

Comment: Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/41320226/8268484